# I have problems with Post method in my CORS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors, access-control

I am developing an app with my own sever, i configured my cors with to by client-side host only. Everything seems to be fine i can request data from my database using the GET, but whenever my trying to POST or create, I always have "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:". Please what am I doing wrong? Below is my code

My server-side

```
const allowedOrigins = [
    'http://localhost:3000/'
]
const CorsOptions = {
    origin: allowedOrigins,
    Credentials: true,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'],
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type'],
    optionsSuccessStatus: 204
}
const cors = require('cors')
const CorsOptions = require('./config/CorsOptions')
app.use(cors(CorsOptions))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.json())
```

My client-side

```
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/workout', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
        })
        const json = await response.json()
        if(!response.ok){
            errors(json.message)
        }
        if(response.ok){
            reset(data)
            console.log('New Workout added successfully', json)
        }
```

The error

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/workout' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

The GET request works perfectly with all these setting above, but for some reason the POST or any other request always gives me this error

I havent done anything yet, i would appreciate any help.

Comment: Try removing the trailing slash in the origin

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most likely a permissions issue,

```html
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

> Configuring CORS headers into server-side code to allow requests from the local host

This header specifies which domains are allowed to make requests to your server.

Comment: No, the problem likely stems from the trailing slash. A Web origin doesn't comprise a path.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Chrome to debug your application, then that could be why, since Chrome doesn't support making POST requests from localhost. A [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743) was made for this, but it was marked as WontFix, so it's likely not going to change any time soon.

[This extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf) circumvents the issue by setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to `*`, along with some other stuff.

You may also want to consider [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-cors-proxy), since you're already using Express.

Hope this helps!